# Problem generating bibliography using Texshop

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, texshop

I'm having serious problems generating a bibliography using `TeXshop`, and I can't for the life of me figure out how to resolve the problem. I've followed all the helpful hints I could find, and nothing!! When I compile using `bibtex` (after doing latex first), I get an error stating that it can't find my `bib` file. My `.bib` file is located in `~Library/texmf/bibtex/bib`, and I'm attempting to call it with `\bibliography{Dissertation}`. Everything I've read says to put the `bib` file in that location, and they all seem to assume that doing so makes everything run fine. So, I haven't been able to find much in the way of advice!

Comment: Try to put it on the same folder as your main `tex` file.

Comment: Have you run `texhash`?

Comment: It should work fine (even without running `texhash`).  Can you run `bibtex` on your file's `.aux` from the command line?  (Note: you don't `bibtex` your `.bib` file.)

Comment: Just a thought, try changing the name of your bib file to `dissertation.bib` (no upper case).  The Mac OS has a funny relation with case sensitivity sometimes.

Comment: As jon pointed, a common error is to try to run `bibtex` on your `.bib` file instead of the `.aux` file. So, assuming your main TeX file is `main.tex` and your BibTeX file is `dissertation.bib`, you need to call `bibtex main` and not `bibtex dissertation.bib`.

Comment: Unrelated, but as you seem to be starting with bibliographies, you should imho jump directly to BibLaTex (and its engine `biber`), the successor of BibTeX!

Comment: @xavier when working from within an IDE like TeXShop it's quite hard to run bibtex on the wrong file.

Comment: @AlanMunn True, though I have had a few friends that used the same IDE to edit their `.tex` and `.bib` files, and got stuck when trying to run bibtex by pressing the "BibTeX button" while editing their `.bib` file (when no parent file was defined).

Comment: @Xavier That didn't occur to me. :) With BibDesk  I never look at the internal state of my bib file.

Comment: @AlanMunn I changed the filename to .bib, but still no luck :( I also tried putting it in the same folder as the .aux file, which is in dropbox, and that didn't do it either. I still get the "I couldn't open database file Dissertation.bib ---line 101 of file Prospectus 2.aux   :  \bibdata{Dissertation}" error. I don't know if it matters but the .bib file was made using Bibdesk....any other ideas? I'm at my wits end! (Also, I'm fairly noobish at technical computer stuff, which doesn't help either).

Comment: I wasn't able to use an absolute path to call my BibTex file, too. Things like `/Users/me/Database/mybibdeskfile` didn't work, but putting it in the same directory as the tex file worked: `BibTex: mybibdeskfile`. I know you already tried it, but maybe you had a typo somewhere, writing paths correctly is highly important. I only mention it because you wrote `~Library/texmf/bibtex/bib`. Using the `~` sign never worked for me (and in your example there should be an `/` after the tilde).